# Non-extractable private key in Keychain Access.app

Tags: security, keychain, encryption, privacy, import

The manual page for `/usr/bin/security` on OS X 10.9 indicates that there is a `-x` option for `security import` to specify that `private keys are non-extractable after being imported`.

How is this implemented?  Are the private keys imported through such means really become completely non-extractable, or is there still a way to get a hold of them through some kind of memory dump?

How do applications still use such keys for their crypto?

---

I've tried using https://github.com/torsten/keychain_access, with the following patch,

```
-    fprintf(stderr, "Export error: %ld\n", status);
+    fprintf(stderr, "Export error: %ld: %s\n", status, CFStringGetCStringPtr(SecCopyErrorMessageString(status, NULL), kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
```

but I'm getting the following error when trying to export the private key,

```
Export error: 4294941980: The contents of this item cannot be retrieved.
```

Is there some other way to get a hold of the non-extractable key?